# emscripten fetch API memory leak

Tags: javascript, emscripten

I'm using emscripten and the associated fetch API to download resources dynamically during runtime. However, it looks like that the memory of each downloaded package is never released.
I boiled it down to a minimal example having the same problem:

https://github.com/sraesch/emscriptenFetchMemoryLeak/tree/master

If I do the same stuff with plain JavaScript, the problem does not appear.
Am I doing something wrong?
Grateful for any help :-)

Comment: Do what stuff? If you have code it could have memory leaks, but we won't know unless you can give us a concrete example.

Comment: A link to code is nice, but having the code directly in your question is even better. Can you explain at what point you expect the downloaded package to be released, and why.

Comment: The code is fairly simple. It just receives a package and releases it immediately. The example is designed to be small, but still having the issue.